# Restricted user folder symlinks

Tags: windows, permissions, symbolic-link, user-folders

In my user folder, (`C:\Users\user`) there are a bunch of symlinks that don't show in File Explorer, even when show>hidden is enabled. I just noticed them because I had my folder open in VS Code. If I try opening one by typing its path into File Explorer, it shows the following popup.
[image: Access denied popup]
I'm able to `Set-Location` to them in admin `pwsh`, but if I try `Get-ChildItem`, it says
`Get-ChildItem: Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\Application Data' is denied.`
In admin `cmd`, `dir`ing them returns

```
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is B426-88EF

 Directory of C:\Users\user\Application Data

File Not Found
```

Here's a list of the links:

```
Application Data
Cookies
Local Settings
My Documents
NetHood
PrintHood
Recent
SendTo
Start Menu
Templates
```

(I haven't tried opening all of them, just a few. If there's a specific one I should try, say so in the comments)

...so my question is: what's the deal with these? Are they some legacy holdover? What's with the super-admin rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft introduced a new folder structure with Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008 and for backwards compatibility reasons, they decided to replace all folders, which have been moved, with a junction point.

Read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/junction-points

The folders and files of a junction point can't be listed, you can only access or create/save/edit a file or folder directly with its full path.
The reason is the ACL of the junction.
[image]

## Example: Create a new folder in `Application Data`

```powershell
New-Item "$Env:USERPROFILE\Application Data\test" -Type Directory
```

Creates the folder `%AppData%\test`

## Example: List directories of an existing sub directory in `Application Data`

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "$Env:USERPROFILE\Application Data\Microsoft"
```

Lists `%AppData%\Microsoft`

## Example: Other junction points and symbolic links on my PC

The following PS command will list all junction points and also symbolic links (like `C:\Users\All Users`, which can be accessed without permission issues) recursively.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Force -Attributes ReparsePoint+System+Hidden -Recurse | 
    ? { $_.FullName -notlike 'C:\Windows.old*' } | Select LinkType, FullName, Target

LinkType     FullName                                                                                          Target
--------     --------                                                                                          ------
Junction     C:\Documents and Settings                                                                         C:\Users
Junction     C:\ProgramData\Application Data                                                                   C:\ProgramData
Junction     C:\ProgramData\Desktop                                                                            C:\Users\Public\Desktop
Junction     C:\ProgramData\Documents                                                                          C:\Users\Public\Documents
Junction     C:\ProgramData\Start Menu                                                                         C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Junction     C:\ProgramData\Templates                                                                          C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
SymbolicLink C:\Users\All Users                                                                                C:\ProgramData
Junction     C:\Users\Default User                                                                             C:\Users\Default
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Application Data                                                                 C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Cookies                                                                          C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Local Settings                                                                   C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\Default\My Documents                                                                     C:\Users\Default\Documents
Junction     C:\Users\Default\NetHood                                                                          C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\Default\PrintHood                                                                        C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Recent                                                                           C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Junction     C:\Users\Default\SendTo                                                                           C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Start Menu                                                                       C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Templates                                                                        C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
Junction     C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Application Data                                                   C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\History                                                            C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
Junction     C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files                                           C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files                         C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Documents\My Music                                                               C:\Users\Default\Music
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Documents\My Pictures                                                            C:\Users\Default\Pictures
Junction     C:\Users\Default\Documents\My Videos                                                              C:\Users\Default\Videos
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Application Data                                                            C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Roaming
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Cookies                                                                     C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Local Settings                                                              C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\My Documents                                                                C:\Users\defaultuser0\Documents
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\NetHood                                                                     C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\PrintHood                                                                   C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Recent                                                                      C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\SendTo                                                                      C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Start Menu                                                                  C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Templates                                                                   C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Application Data                                              C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\History                                                       C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files                                      C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files                    C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5                       C:\Users\defaultuser0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Documents\My Music                                                          C:\Users\defaultuser0\Music
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Documents\My Pictures                                                       C:\Users\defaultuser0\Pictures
Junction     C:\Users\defaultuser0\Documents\My Videos                                                         C:\Users\defaultuser0\Videos
Junction     C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Music                                                                C:\Users\Public\Music
Junction     C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Pictures                                                             C:\Users\Public\Pictures
Junction     C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Videos                                                               C:\Users\Public\Videos
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Application Data                                                                   C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Roaming
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Cookies                                                                            C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Local Settings                                                                     C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\My Documents                                                                       C:\Users\svenw\Documents
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\NetHood                                                                            C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\PrintHood                                                                          C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Recent                                                                             C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\SendTo                                                                             C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Start Menu                                                                         C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Templates                                                                          C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Application Data                                                     C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\History                                                              C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files                                             C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files                           C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5                              C:\Users\svenw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Documents\My Music                                                                 C:\Users\svenw\Music
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Documents\My Pictures                                                              C:\Users\svenw\Pictures
Junction     C:\Users\svenw\Documents\My Videos                                                                C:\Users\svenw\Videos
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Application Data                                                                    C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Cookies                                                                             C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Local Settings                                                                      C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\Test\My Documents                                                                        C:\Users\Test\Documents
Junction     C:\Users\Test\NetHood                                                                             C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\Test\PrintHood                                                                           C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Recent                                                                              C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Junction     C:\Users\Test\SendTo                                                                              C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Start Menu                                                                          C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Templates                                                                           C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
Junction     C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Application Data                                                      C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\History                                                               C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
Junction     C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files                                              C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files                            C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Documents\My Music                                                                  C:\Users\Test\Music
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Documents\My Pictures                                                               C:\Users\Test\Pictures
Junction     C:\Users\Test\Documents\My Videos                                                                 C:\Users\Test\Videos
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Application Data                                               C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Roaming
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Cookies                                                        C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Local Settings                                                 C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\My Documents                                                   C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Documents
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\NetHood                                                        C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\PrintHood                                                      C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Recent                                                         C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\SendTo                                                         C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Start Menu                                                     C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Templates                                                      C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\Application Data                                 C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\History                                          C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files                         C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files       C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Documents\My Music                                             C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Music
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Documents\My Pictures                                          C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Pictures
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Documents\My Videos                                            C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\MariaDB\Videos
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Application Data                                         C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Roaming
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Cookies                                                  C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Local Settings                                           C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\My Documents                                             C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Documents
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\NetHood                                                  C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\PrintHood                                                C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Recent                                                   C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\SendTo                                                   C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Start Menu                                               C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Templates                                                C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\Application Data                           C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\History                                    C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files                   C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Documents\My Music                                       C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Music
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Documents\My Pictures                                    C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Pictures
Junction     C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Documents\My Videos                                      C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\UIFlowService\Videos
Junction     C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5    C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE
```

Comment: That list of "junction points" will also include any symbolic links, which are also reparse points. For instance, C:\Users\All Users.

Comment: @kreemoweet Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my last example.